# amend commit in git and merge to master without conflicts| Gerrit

Tags: git, git-merge, gerrit

I have a master branch from which I create a dev branch.

I make a commit "test" in dev branch.

Take a pull in master.

merge feature to master and push the code.

Now if I have a review comment in [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) the pushed code thus it is nit merged, I have to amend the same commit.

How can I do so? If I make amend the commit in dev branch and merge it again with master I get conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to make a new patch set on a Change that is on review:

1. On your master branch checkout the change (Use the download button on the Gerrit UI).
2. Create a local branch (because you will be with a detached head) `git checkout -b new_branch_name`
3. Make the changes required and `git add` them.
4. Amend the commit using `git commit --amend`, and make sure you don't change the Change-Id on the commit message.
5. Push your changes back.

Comment: But I only want to do it using my git.

Comment: @boomcode But why? The only step you need the gerrit ui is to copy the checkout command. Would you be ok with using `git-review`?

Comment: This works fine! One question though. What if my new change conflicts with some code. How can I check it since I have not taken a pull?

Comment: You can do `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/master` to rebase your commit on the top of master before pushing. So if there was some new code on master that conflicts with your changes, you can solve them, amend again and push.

Comment: I made a dev branch, made a commit "test", pulled at master to make the code latest in master and merged the dev branch to master and pushed the commit. Now I follow your process to make a new branch by checking out the change from master. But since master itself now has the pushed and unmerged local commit "test" when i try to merge the latest branch with master it shows conflicts with my code which I introduced in "test" in the first commit

Comment: Ok, your local master is the "problem". You can `git reset --hard origin/master`, this will let it exactly like the remote. You shouldn't have any problems merging/rebasing then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132770/discussion-between-boomcode-and-nogoseke).